# How to use @JDBCDBColumn for typ ahead in xpages

Tags: oracle, jdbc, xpages, rdbms

Using Notes 9 and extension library's data controls...

I want to use the @JDBCDbColumn() to get the type ahead values from an Oracle table.

Is that possible at all?  Does it work the same way the standard DBColumn in the type ahead?

Note that the DBColumn is looking in a huge table, but I specify a where clause that should filter what the JDBCDBColumn returns.

Somehow, nothing happens.  Work sfine with Notes data though, but I need to get this working with the Oracle data.

Thanks!

Update 1: Code I have...

```
@JdbcExecuteQuery(
    "oracle",
    "select distinct postal_code from cifadmin.postal_codes where postal_code like '"
      + getComponent("CodePostal").getValue() + "%'")
```

Update 2: Here is the code I have right now, but it doesn't return anything:

```
var CodePostal = getComponent("rsSearchQuery").getValue();
if(!!CodePostal) {
    var params = [CodePostal];
    var a = @JdbcDbColumn("oracle", "postal_codes", "postal_code", "postal_code like ?", params); 
    return @Unique(a);
} else {
    return "--";
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? I may have a chance to look at it tomorrow morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working thanks to all your comments and a bit of intuition!!!

Here is the working code:

```
var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT POSTAL_CODE FROM cifadmin.POSTAL_CODES WHERE POSTAL_CODE LIKE'" +     getComponent("PostalCode").getValue() +"%' ORDER BY POSTAL_CODE";
var res = @JdbcExecuteQuery("oracle", sql);
var values = new Array();
while (res.next()) {
values.push(res.getString("POSTAL_CODE"));
}   
return values;
```

The thing that got it working was when I have forced 'values' as an array.  Without that, it just doesn't work.

Picky and sensitive, XPages are!!!

Thanks to all for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it the first time ever: works fine for me except I didn't use a WHERE clause in my sample and another type of DB here.

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" styleClass="form-control">
                    <xp:typeAhead mode="partial" minChars="1" ignoreCase="true">
                        <xp:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:@JdbcDbColumn("postgres", "xpagesdemo.names", "lastname")}]]></xp:this.valueList>
                    </xp:typeAhead>
                </xp:inputText>
```

See live demo here: http://www.notesx.net/postgres.nsf/typeahead.xsp

Comment: Problem I have is that the table is a list of addresses (20 Millions +) and I want a list of all the cities, therefore the where clause.

If I use the @JDBCDbColumn with a hard coded where clause that returns only a few values (100), it works fine.


Code I have:

@JdbcExecuteQuery("oracle","select distinct postal_code from cifadmin.postal_codes where postal_code like '"+getComponent("CodePostal").getValue()+"%'")

We can't modify the Oracle DB so we have to work with that limitation...

Comment: Does your @JdbcExecuteQuery work? By the way, you should use SQL parameters and not build your select statement with concatenating strings where one string is user input. That can open up your app to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Howard, the problem is that the JDBCExecute returns a result set and we would need to renderthe incoming results.  It is a possibility, but I was wandering if we could get the where clause of the JDBCDbColumn to act like the SQL "like 'value%'".

Thanks for the tip on the SQL Parameter though: I was just reading this lesson this morning!!!  ;)

Comment: Here is the code I have right now, but it doesn't return anything:
`var CodePostal = getComponent("rsSearchQuery").getValue();
if(!!CodePostal) {
 var params = [CodePostal];
 var a = @JdbcDbColumn("oracle", "postal_codes", "postal_code", "postal_code like ?", params);
 return @Unique(a);
} else {
 return "--";
}`

Answer (score 0):

Ben, I think you mean you want to put the wildcard to the end of the parameter? Not sure of your data and if you are entering an exact match? Did you try:

var params = [CodePostal+ "%"];

Also, not sure if you need to enter "cifadmin.postal_codes" for your table as you did in your sql?

Howard